# What is the reason for this site's sudden drop in traffic?

Tags: traffic, google-ranking

My one site's traffic has dropped in single day from around 4000 to 800 visitors. My other sites are getting normal visitor count.

I'm not using any blackhat techniques nor trading links or having a bad neighbourhood or any copied materies. But yes it's a pdf documents download site with bounce rate of 32% and 3.5 pageviews per person.

No issues reported in Google webmastertools. I find that for the relevant keywords my site has been pushed far way in Google.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT**
I've uploaded two updated reports( webmaster top keywords and analytics 1 month graph). 
[image: google analytics 1 month graph till yesterday)28th)]

---

---

[image: Today's updated webmaster's top queries report from 22nd-26th(Monday)]

Comment: Which traffic source is showing the drop? Search, referral or direct?

Comment: In Google queries most of my site's pages have been pushed down which were usually in the first page(within 50 results).

Comment: It's increasing now and yesterday it touched 1500.

Comment: Let me tell the traffic jumped back. Looks like some Google internal issue.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is a sudden drop!

The only things that I can think of is:

- Is it a seasonal drop? ie. Did you notice a similar change around
  the holidays last year?
- Has the website experienced any downtime/load issues?
- Perhaps Google has rolled out another Panda Update. There were murmurings of another one being rolled out last week and into this week. Wait and see how traffic changes over the next week of so. If things remain the same, Google probably has changed the 'value' of the site and you might need to think of ways to make it more content rich. (All this year, previously high traffic websites with little unique textual content have experienced suden drastic reductions in traffic.)

Comment: The site is 1 year old and there are no downtime/load issues as my other sites are quite fine in my Hostgator shared hosting account. Looks like some sort of Panda update.

Answer (score 2):

Check all the files which have been indexed and see is any of your files has been de-indexed. If that's the case then some is going wrong in your website, and you should explain more if you want us to help you.
Check and see if your ranking has been dropped in SRP (search result page).

**EDIT**
It mostly seems that Google has penalized your site for a specific reason!
Give your URL maybe we could address the problem.

Comment: Yes ranking has been dropped in the SERP. How to check which pages are indexed? I find pages to be indexed but pushed down in the SERP to unreasonable end to the extent that site which will not satisfy searcher are in the top.

Comment: See the edit @John

Comment: http://www.downloadformsindia.com

Comment: All your `Most popular` and `Latest Forms` links give 404 not found. I think you should really think about all of those broken pages. IMHO that's unlikely you are punished for any other reason.

Comment: Thanks I've checked just now they are all fine and also there aren't any crawl errors reported in Google webmastertools

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Velvet,

It may be because of New Year holiday or

Your website was down. or

Google has rolled out another Panda Update.